# FileZilla Server connection fails when switching to explicit SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, ftp

I've configured FileZilla server successfully (without SSL/TLS) by port forwarding:

-Modem (external ISP address): TCP 21, 990, 50000-50100 -> 10.1.10.10

-Router (external 10.1.10.10): TCP 21, 990, 50000-50100 -> 192.168.1.61 (server)

And allowing Windows Firewall TCP(and UDP) ports 21, 990 and 50000-50100. I also set FileZilla server to use a custom port range for passive mode (50000-50100)

### However

As soon as I enable the following checkboxes in FileZilla server:

- Enable FTP over SSL/TLS support (FTPS)
- Allow explicit FTP over TLS
- Disallow plain unencrypted FTP
- For PROT P to encrypt file transfers in SSL/TLS mode

The connection is made (accept the certificate), but the client fails at the `MLSD` command after entering passive mode.

Does explicit SSL/TLS use different ports? If I try *implicit* SSL (port 990) the connection isn't even made. I would settle for either type of secure connection working.

Answer (score 0):

Your explicit connection is likely being killed by stateful packet inspection (SPI) or deep packet inspection (DPI) of your router.  You should be able to disable that and/or add an exception for the MLSD command.

Your implicit connection needs TCP 989 for the data channel.

Comment: I don't think my router (WRT54G) has SPI, nor the modem. I also opened TCP 989 on modem, router and server. The implicit connection still hangs (doesn't ever connect)